# Simple equation solving

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a matrix 2x2 over $R$ and in after puting it to linear equation it looks like this $(3,2,1,-4),(1,0,0,-1).$$$ \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2  \\ 1 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix} $$
I need to show that it equals to:

$(3x+y,2x,x,-4x-y)$

Trying to solve it for 15min already and Im missing something. Can anyone show me how to approach this question?

Comment: your question is not at all clear. what does it mean to say putting it into linear equations?

Comment: when you have a $2*2$ matrix, how come you have four tuple??

Comment: Edited. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Too long for a comment}$

presumably you are trying to get $$ \mathbf{M} =\begin{pmatrix} 3x+y & 2x  \\ x & -4x-y \\ \end{pmatrix} $$? (assuming that you transform like you did for the other 2$\times$2 matrix to the "4 tuple" )
Now by linear are you talking about

$$
\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{A}x + \mathbf{B}y
$$
where 
$$
\mathbf{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 2  \\ 1 & -4 \\ \end{pmatrix},\\
\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & -1 \\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
and x and y are just scalars?  which achieves the desired result

or are you working with $\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x  \\ y \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and performing a linear operation?

My above comment contains a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Yup. It is M = Ax + By.

Comment: Ah good good. Glad to help.